# PyQt5 translation: is it possible to run pylupdate5 from Python?

Tags: qt, pyqt, translation, qt-linguist

I have some PyQt5 application with some `tr()` translations in it. I have a Python script that compiles UI forms and resources, and I want it to also update the `ts` file with translations, because it's a bit annoying to run pylupdate manually each time.

Alas, I haven't find any information, how to run the Python functions that provide translation file compilation in PyQt5. Haven't you ever got the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it like this

```
import os
ret = os.system("E:\Anaconda3\Library\\bin\\pylupdate5.exe -verbose Main.py otherfile.py thirdfile.py -ts zh_CN.ts")
```

Hopefully you found it as well